# How do I recognize what string from a list is closest to my input?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a school project and have a function that recognized a comment and finds the information from the comment and writes it down to a file. When how could I check an input string against a list of strings of information. Like if I have an input

```
input = "How many fingers do I have?"
```

How do I check which of these is closest to it?

```
fingers = "You have 10."
pigs = "yummy"
```

I want it to respond with fingers. I want to match it with the variable name and not the variable's value.

Comment: First you have to define what "closest" means.

Comment: This site is for helping people with problems they're stuck on. Please don't start with "I'm doing this (homework/project/test)..." as people are far less inclined to assist you. I also recommend demonstrating your theories/ideas or any attempts to solve the problem if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read this chapter. 
This is a chapter from Natural Language Processing with Python, by Steven Bird, Ewan Klein and Edward Loper.

> Detecting patterns is a central part of Natural Language Processing.
>   Words ending in -ed tend to be past tense verbs (5). Frequent use of
>   will is indicative of news text (3). These observable patterns — word
>   structure and word frequency — happen to correlate with particular
>   aspects of meaning, such as tense and topic. But how did we know where
>   to start looking, which aspects of form to associate with which
>   aspects of meaning?
>
> The goal of this chapter is to answer the following questions:
>
> How can we identify particular features of language data that are
>   salient for classifying it? How can we construct models of language
>   that can be used to perform language processing tasks automatically?
>   What can we learn about language from these models?

It all described in python, and it's very efficient.

http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html

Also, processing the text by using a keyword that matches a variable name is not good and not efficient. I won't recommend it.